# Sized Data Load in Golang (Getting uint16 into a uint8 slice)

Tags: go

I'm hacking together a rough ISS of a processor and I wonder if there is a more efficient way to to what I am doing (ideally without resorting to the unsafe library).
(Simplified) I'm representing memory by:

```
type DataMem []uint8
```

a register by:

```
type Register uint16
```

Memory needs to be in byte sized units and the processor works in larger units as above. This means to store the data we do:

```
func (m *Machine) ExecuteST (ins Instruction) {
  // Store to memory
  // Data to store specified in one register
  // Address to store to specified by another register
  target_address := m.RegBank[ins.Dst]
  src_data := m.RegBank[ins.Src]

  ///////// Start of annoying section////////
  var target_0 uint8
  var target_1 uint8
  target_0 =  src_data & 0x0f
  target_1 = (src_data & 0xf0)>>8
  m.data_mem[target_address  ] = target_0
  m.data_mem[target_address+1] = target_1
  /////////// End of annoying section /////////
  m.logger.Printf("ST To Address %x, Data %x\n",target_address,src_data)
}
```

And so on for all sorts of different data types and transfers.

The annoying thing for me is I know the processor that the go code will be running on will have a single load instruction that *could* do all of the above in a single transfer. I'd expect a good c compiler to optimise into that for me, but without breaking out the unsafe library and going straight to the pointers I don't think I can get around this?

I'm open for suggestions including better ways to model the data memory...

Comment: I don't know about a better way to do what you're doing, but your masks are wrong. The first one should be `0xff` and the other should be `0xff00`.

Comment: Oops, thanks! I'd re-written the code from what I was running to simplify the problem - looks like I simplified incorrectly/too quickly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the type safety of Go, there's not much you can do differently here without using the unsafe package.

The simplest solution, and probably the most performant, is to do the conversion on the target address:

```
// convert the target address to *uint16
srcData = uint16(0xeeee)
*(*uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(&dataMem[targetAddress])) = srcData
```

Similarly, another option is to shadow the `[]uint8` slice with a `[]uint16` slice pointing to the same memory region. This looks even more hairy, and you have to check your offsets and alignment yourself.

```
dataMem16 := (*(*[1<<30 - 1]uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(&dataMem[0])))[:len(dataMem)/2 : len(dataMem)/2]
dataMem16[targetAddress/2] = srcData
```

One other option to try is using the builtin `copy` to move the bytes. Since copy is implemented in assembly by the compiler, it may do what you want (though I haven't checked what the assembly of the conversion actually produces, so it could be a wash)

```
copy(dataMem[targetAddress:], (*(*[2]uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(&srcData)))[:])
```

Or as an inline-able function as @OneOfOne shows:

```
func regToMem(reg uint16) *[2]uint8 {
    return (*[2]uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(&reg))
}

copy(mem[targetAddress:], regToMem(0xffff)[:])
```

https://play.golang.org/p/0c1UywVuzj

If performance is critical, and you want to use architecture specific instructions, the "proper" way to do this would be to implement what you want directly in assembly, but the code generated from the first solution would probably be hard to beat.

Comment: Damn it, stop ninjaing my answers out of my brain Jim! anywho https://play.golang.org/p/C8jo2Jk59R

Comment: @OneOfOne: thanks, that's a little nicer looking for the first case

Comment: Thanks very much for this TBH I prefer the slice shadowing as that should work without any risk of adding extra operations on top of the move - copy may add other things. But a useful tool to add to the bag of tricks.

Comment: @ChrisHopkins: I missed probably the simplest solution, converting the target address to uint16 rather than copying 2 bytes. It's essentially the same as converting the entire slice, but I think it's a little less error prone and easier to reason about. I would only use the last option of you have to do lots of random access within that memory region.

Answer (score 0):

Since what I care about is efficiency of the simulation another option is to declare the data memory differently e.g.

```
type DataMem []uint32
```

The provide methods that given an address exctract the byte

```
func (dm *DataMem) StoreB (address int) uint8 {...}
func (dm *DataMem) Store16 (address int) uint16 {...}
```

Given this is running on a PC there will be a data cache there so fetching too large a data word will not cost anything on a modern processor.

I need a new cardinal rule, when you have a tricky problem, look at the data structures and your platform ;-)